# I have a form with action to open multiplefiles. Upon clicking the action and canceling from Open file popup is there a way to reset?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, getopenfilename

I have a form with action to open multiplefiles. Upon clicking the action and canceling from Open file popup is there a way reset the action and just show the form without executing the module b

Private Sub btnImport_Click()

```
Call moduleA
Call moduleB
```

End Sub

Sub moduleA()

for nfile = 1 to nfiles

selection = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Open File", "Open", False)
If selection = False Then
Exit For
End If

Next nfile

End sub